# Identifying Errors in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2016

With my stored procedure, I am attempting to find the number of `Recommendations` per `CityID`, and I am having syntax-related trouble. I have included the error messages at the bottom.**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [Kittens_Dogs_AGGREGATE].[dbo].[sp_RecommendationsPerSite]
    
USE [Kittens_Dogs_AGGREGATE]
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    -- =============================================
    -- Author:      Tom Brady
    -- Create date: 12/27/2019
    -- Description: This script is to check for the amount of recommendations per site
    -- =============================================
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_RecommendationsPerSite] 
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 DECLARE @CityID NVARCHAR(50),
         @RunDate DATETIME = CAST(GETDATE() as date),
         @DepartureTime DATETIME,
         @ApplesOranges NVARCHAR(250),
         @RollerCoaster NVARCHAR(50))
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SELECT @RApplesOranges AS ApplesOranges, Count(DISTINCT @RollerCoaster) AS RollerCoaster
        FROM [Kittens_Dogs_AGGREATE].[dbo].[Recommendations] b
        WHERE @CityID = 210
        AND cast(@DepartureTime as date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS NVARCHAR)
        AND a.ApplesOranges = b.ApplesOranges
        AND cast(@DepartureTime as date) <> cast(@RunDate as date) as '2019-12-27' -- ,(select count(DISTINCT RollerCoaster)
        FROM [Kittnes_Dogs_AGGREGATE].[dbo].[Recommendations] b
        WHERE CityID = 210
        AND cast(@DepartureDate as date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS NVARCHAR)
        AND a.ApplesOranges = b.ApplesOranges
        AND cast(@DepartureDate as date) <> cast(@RunDate as date)) as CAST(GETDATE() - 1 AS NVARCHAR)
        FROM [Kittens_Dogs_AGGREGATE].[dbo].[Recommendations] a
        WHERE CityID = 210
        GROUP BY ApplesOranges
        ORDER BY 1
    
    END
    GO
```

---

**Error Messages**

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_RecommendationsPerSite, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 22]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_RecommendationsPerSite, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 22]
> Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: The string "DECLARE" is not in the code in your question, so the first error is not related to this code.

Comment: Don't even see `declare` in your code.

Comment: Couple of FYIs: [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix), [Bad habits to kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal) and [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Comment: Also, why are you converting `GETDATE` to an `nvarchar` and then comparing it to a `date`..?

Comment: @Larnu I am trying to Get the current date and time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just changed it

Comment: `AS` is missing at the start of the SP's declaration.

Comment: `@RunDate DATETIME = CAST(GETDATE() as date)` 

`GETDATE()` returns a `DATETIME`, why would you need to cast it as a `DATE`?

Comment: *" I am trying to Get the current date and time."* So why an `nvarchar`? That isn't a date or time, it's just a string.

Comment: There are too many bugs to fix.

Comment: You never assign a value to `@DepartureTime` either, so even if this didn't error, it would never return a result set.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things going on here.

Your second error is in the last line of your parameter definitions: `@RollerCoaster NVARCHAR(50))` you have an extra ')' at the end.

Next your select statement will fail because you have multiple FROM and WHERE clauses. It looks like you tried to comment it out, but `--` only comments a line.

Comment: Those aren't parameters, they're variables that are being declared in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

try this

all the problem seems to reside in the declare wrongly put

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_RecommendationsPerSite] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 (@CityID NVARCHAR(50),
     @RunDate DATETIME = CAST(GETDATE() as date),
     @DepartureTime DATETIME,
     @ApplesOranges NVARCHAR(250),
     @RollerCoaster NVARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SELECT @RApplesOranges AS ApplesOranges, Count(DISTINCT @RollerCoaster) AS RollerCoaster
    FROM [Kittens_Dogs_AGGREATE].[dbo].[Recommendations] b
    WHERE @CityID = 210
    AND cast(@DepartureTime as date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS NVARCHAR)
    AND a.ApplesOranges = b.ApplesOranges
    AND cast(@DepartureTime as date) <> cast(@RunDate as date) as '2019-12-27' -- ,(select count(DISTINCT Patient)
    FROM [Kittnes_Dogs_AGGREGATE].[dbo].[Recommendations] b
    WHERE CityID = 210
    AND cast(@DepartureDate as date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS NVARCHAR)
    AND a.ApplesOranges = b.ApplesOranges
    AND cast(@DepartureDate as date) <> cast(@RunDate as date)) as CAST(GETDATE() - 1 AS NVARCHAR)
    FROM [Kittens_Dogs_AGGREGATE].[dbo].[Recommendations] a
    WHERE CityID = 210
    GROUP BY ApplesOranges
    ORDER BY 1

END
```